# How to get (static) access token for facebook

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have a backend server which will access the FB Graph Api.
As part of the requests to FB Graph Api I want to provide the Access Token.

I wonder how and where I can generate such a (static) access token which should never expire.
Note that I'm not calling the api for logged in users, but just for our backend server.

Note that we have a Facebook Page so if we would be able to generate a Access Token for this 'account' it would be sufficient I would think, but where/how to do this.

We are doing something similar for Twitter, but there we just create an app, and generate the access token. Works perfectly.

Comment: I think this [post][1] may help you


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18261813/what-are-the-steps-to-getting-a-long-lasting-token-for-posting-to-a-facebook-fan/18322405#18322405